# Prevent Pandas from unpacking a tuple when creating a dataframe from dict

Tags: python, pandas

When creating a DataFrame in Pandas from a dictionary, a tuple is automatically expanded, i.e.

```
import pandas
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': (3,4)}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df)
```

returns

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
```

Apart from converting the tuple to string first, is there any way to prevent this from happening? I would want the result to be

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add `[]`, so value in `dictionary` with key `c` is `list` of `tuple`:

```
import pandas

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [(3,4)]}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

print(df)
   a  b       c
0  1  2  (3, 4)
```

Comment: The solution shouldn't require to change the type of d['c'] from tuple to list.

Answer (score 1):

Pass param `orient='index'` and transpose the result so it doesn't broadcast the scalar values:

```
In [13]:
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': (3,4)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
df

Out[13]:
   a       c  b
0  1  (3, 4)  2
```

To handle the situation where the first dict entry is a tuple, you'd need to enclose all the dict values into a list so it's iterable:

```
In [20]:
d = {'a': (5,6), 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
d1 = dict(zip(d.keys(), [[x] for x in d.values()]))
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index').T

Out[23]:
        a  b  c
0  (5, 6)  2  1
```

Comment: This won't work if the first value (dicts are ordered in python) is the tuple: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: @kilgoretrout to workaround that you'd have to construct a new dict wrapping all the dict values into a list so that the values are iterable and the len can be deduced, see updated answer. It's not ideal but this would get around that error